# How can i make directory listing possible in my prestashop website?

Tags: prestashop, directory-listing

How to show the files in the directory listing in my prestashop website. I want to make the directory listing possible in my prestashop website. Like example: www.chakras-music.com/prestashop/modules/

Comment: Can you describe what do you want exactly..

Comment: Please make your question self-contained by explaining what you want. Just a URL is not enough and we also don't know what's behind the URL.

Answer (score 1):

you have to redirect to a folder 
that folder should not contain a index file (index.html 0r index.php)